# How to save data in parquet format and append entries

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am trying to follow this [example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html#save-modes) to save some data in parquet format and read it. If I use the `write.parquet("filename")`, then the iterating Spark job gives error that

> "filename" already exists.

If I use `SaveMode.Append` option, then the Spark job gives the error

> ".spark.sql.AnalysisException: Specifying database name or other qualifiers are not allowed for temporary tables".

Please let me know the best way to ensure new data is just appended to the parquet file. Can I define primary keys on these parquet tables?

I am using Spark 1.6.2 on Hortonworks 2.5 system. Here is the code:

```
// Option 1: peopleDF.write.parquet("people.parquet")
//Option 2:
 peopleDF.write.format("parquet").mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("people.parquet")

// Read in the parquet file created above
val parquetFile = spark.read.parquet("people.parquet")

//Parquet files can also be registered as tables and then used in SQL statements.
parquetFile.registerTempTable("parquetFile")
val teenagers = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM people.parquet")
```

Comment: One approach is to read the whole data as a Dataframe,  delete the file using FileSystem api and then dumped the data again as parquet file

Answer (score 4):

I believe if you use `.parquet("....")`, you should use `.mode('append')`,
not `SaveMode.Append`:

`df.write.mode('append').parquet("....")`

Comment: See the [Save Modes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#save-modes) section of the documentation

Comment: Here's an updated [Save Modes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html#save-modes) link.  The above doesn't go to Save Modes anymore.